# Заливка ячеек в столбце по условию. Случайное распределение

Tags: excel, vba, office, excel-формулы

В ячейке F3 и G3 генерируются случайные числа. Сумма ячеек всегда 100. Необходимо в диапазоне C2:C101 в случайным порядке окрасить зеленым кол-во ячеек равное F3 и красным кол-во ячеек равное G3. Спасибо!

Comment: А можете показать ваш код, как Вы делали и что не получилось?

Comment: @СергейПряничкин кода нет, как и идей как это сделать.

Comment: Используйте Rnd (https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/rnd-function) и проверки на количества IF (https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/752y8abs%28v=vs.120%29.aspx). И Циклы типа FOR (https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/5z06z1kb(v=vs.120).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Упростим: заливаем весь диапазон красным, потом зеленым количество ячеек равное *F3*

```
Sub RangeColor()
Dim aRnd(), rRng As Range
Dim lVal As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Application.Calculate
    lVal = Cells(3, 6).Value

    If lVal > 0 Then
        ReDim aRnd(1 To 100)
        Randomize

        For i = 1 To 100
            j = Int(Rnd * i + 1)
            If j <> i Then aRnd(i) = aRnd(j)
            aRnd(j) = i
        Next i

        Set rRng = Cells(aRnd(1) + 1, 3)

        For i = 2 To lVal
            Set rRng = Union(rRng, Cells(aRnd(i) + 1, 3))
        Next i
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Range("C2:C101").Interior.Color = RGB(200, 0, 0)
    Range("C2:C101").Value = "П"

    If Not rRng Is Nothing Then
        rRng.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 200, 0)
        rRng.Value = "В"
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set rRng = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Возможно как то `RGB(0, 200, 0) ` поменять на слова "зеленый" ? В дальнейшем мне будет необходима формула с ЕСЛИ, а `RGB(0, 200, 0) ` туда не засунешь

Comment: Увы, не получится - формулы не умеют определять формат ячеек. Можно при заливке зеленым в ячейку заносить значение и формулой смотреть не цвет, а наличие значения.

Comment: Подскажите как изменить ваш код, чтобы ячейки с зеленым получали букву В, а ячейки с красным букву П

Comment: Заменил код (дополнен вставкой значений)